# How can I show directive in .html from .ts file

Tags: angular

So what I'm trying to do is to show a directive which include a message "You haven't type anything" in case when user didn't type a single symbol into an input panel.

Under 'else' I tried to show result in the console - it worked just fine. But I completely can't understand how to link it to the #tooShort directive.

My .html looks like this:

```
<input style="width:100%; border:1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; height: 15px;" [(ngModel)]="newTask">
<button (click)="add()">Add task</button>

<ng-template #tooShort>
<div class="center">
<p>You haven't write anything</p>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

And my .ts:

```
newTask: string;
tasksList: Array<string> = [];


add() {
    if(this.newTask!=""){
    this.tasksList.push(this.newTask);
    this.newTask = "";
  } else
    document.body.innerHTML = "tooShort";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not modifly html directly (bad practice).
In this case you can use your formgroup:

```
<div *ngIf="form.newTask.value < 1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are gettin git all wrong.
I think wha you need is this.

```
   <input style="width:100%; border:1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; 
    height: 
      15px;" [(ngModel)]="newTask">
    <button (click)="add()">Add task</button>

    <div class="center">
      <p #tooShort>You haven't write anything</p>
    </div>
```

in ts :

```
@ViewChild('tooShort') tooShort: ElementRef;

add() {
  if (this.newTask !== '') {
   this.tasksList.push(this.newTask);
   this.newTask = '';
   this.tooShort.nativeElement.innerText = '';
} else {
   this.tooShort.nativeElement.innerText = 'tooshort';
 }
}
```

However you should not directly manipulate the dom like this . You should better create a directive and do it with renderer or simple show a text based on value.